# How to convert from C++ bool to Python boolean with Boost Python?

Tags: python, c++, boost, boolean

I've been trying to make a conversion function from C++ types (like std::string and int) to convert to boost::python::object but the [Boost docs about objects](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/object.html) didn't specify anything about bools.

```
boost::python::object convert_to_python_bool(bool input_bool) {
    return boost::python::boost_python_bool_type(input_bool);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found out you have to explicitly convert to boost::python::object and there is no special class like boost::python::bool_ or anything like that:

```
boost::python::object convert_to_python_bool(bool input_bool) {
    return boost::python::object(input_bool);
}
```